# Pokemon Go can't be downloaded on Android 4.4

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I have a Samsung Galaxy Core2 with Android 4.4.2, and the the Pokemon Go app doesn't show in my Play Store.
I tried finding the app on my PC, adding it to my wishlist and then going to mobile again, but it says that my device is incompatible.
Is it, or do I have to do something else to make it work?

P.s. I had just formatted my phone, but I restarted it several times. I don't know if it has something to do with it not working. The app has been released in my country (Greece).

Answer (score 4):

It could be that your phone really isn't compatible. Pokemon Go's system requirements are as follows:

> #### Android
>
> - Android 6 or above
> - Preferred resolution of 720 x 1280 pixels (not optimized for tablet)
> - Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
> - GPS and Location Services
> - Rooted devices are not supported
>
> #### iOS
>
> - iPhone 6s or above
> - iOS 13 or above
> - Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
> - GPS and Location Services
> - Jailbroken devices are not supported
>
> <sub>Last updated March 2022, check [Niantic's Supported Devices](https://niantic.helpshift.com/hc/en/6-pokemon-go/faq/92-supported-devices/) for up-to-date specifications</sub>

With that being said, if [this is your phone](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_core_ii-6331.php) then its resolution of 480 x 800 pixels doesn't meet the minimum specifications

Comment: My S3 is on Android 4.4 but isn't compatible with GO, I just had to use a newer phone in the end. So beware: Android version isn't a hard guarantee that it *will* be compatible, just that it *might* be.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually a bit disappointed that they didn't include better information on their site regarding compatible devices

Comment: well , i guess that i will need a new phone (again) i just exchanged it with my sister...some days ago was saying that it is compatible.. 
thanks guys u were helpfull! :)

Comment: @Goldy You're welcome, sorry it wasn't the information you wanted.  Don't forget to mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If Google says your device is not compatible, you will be unable to install Pokemon Go, even if you download the apk (the installation will fail with some sort of error).

However, there might still be a way for you to play Pokemon Go, but it is complicated and full of risks. In order to get it working, you would need to root your phone, install a newer version of Android on your phone (either the default one or a custom ROM like Cyanogenmod), install Google Apps (Gapps) on it if  they aren't shipped, and finally install the Pokemon Go apk from an external source like Apkmirror or Aptoide, because Google won't let you download it even with a more up to date OS. But with the new OS you will be able to install it.

It works (I couldn't have run Pokemon Go on my device either because the system was too old and no updates were provided), but be aware that a rooted phone loses ots warranty and **always** do a full backup before doing/flashing anything risky!

If you can go this way also depends on if there are ROMs available for your device - if there is none, you can forget the idea.

**Edit:** You said in a comment you'd buy a new phone - if you would do that if it doesn't work anyways, its definetely worth a try, because rooted phones have many more advantages than just a new OS! You will also be able to highly cudtomize everything on your phone and using things like Xposed and XPrivacy (lets you restrict any unwanted permissions from any app) you'll have a great time! S3 smartphones should even have the newest official CyanogenMod ROM available... Go for it, there's nothing you could loose!

Answer (score -3):

People you don't need no root or jailbreak,all you have to do is install apptoide,and then install Pokemon GO.You can delete apptoide afterwards.

Comment: Well, you might be able to get the APK, but when the phone isn't compatible I highly doubt you can install/start GO.